# "Floor" brackets touching in cases

Tags: math-mode, brackets, size

What is the nicest way to prevent the "floor brackets" from touching in this example?

[image]

```
\alpha=
\begin{cases}
\left\lfloor \frac{(a_1+b_1)^2}{4} \right\rfloor & x \\
\left\lfloor \frac{(a_2+b_2)^2}{4} \right\rfloor & y \\
\end{cases}
```

This is a minimal example. The real example also has fractions where the numerator is a square of some subscripted terms.

I could use `\bigl` and `\bigr` but then the brackets look a bit short.

Comment: This works correctly for your question: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[\alpha=
\begin{cases}
\left\lfloor \frac{(a_1+b_1)^2}{4} \right\rfloor & x \\[.7em]%%%%%<----it is a good measure.
\left\lfloor \frac{(a_2+b_2)^2}{4} \right\rfloor & y 
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}`

Comment: @Sebastiano Yep, found it shortly after I posted the question, so I voted to close as duplicate of a QA suggestion the same. Thank you!

Comment: Don't worry, :-) :-) ....you're welcome. I have not read the link.